# ADMOB: Why my match rate never increase?

Tags: android, admob

I have a game deployed in the store, here are some app and admob metrics:

- It makes ~120k requests per day
- It have ~800 active devices in the last 30 days
- It have less than 1% match rate(~0.3%)
- Some math: 120k/0.8k(800) -> ~ 150 requests per user(really high I think)

I have read some articles and questions about this, what I did was:

- Make sure to only request an ad when it needs to be displayed, I can't always ensure this, but I tried my best.
- Make sure my app are not enrolled in the 'Designed for Families' program.
- Make sure my ad content rating is for mature audiences(M).

All this was done last week, since then I have seen not a single change in the admob reports, everything stills the same, after changing the request rate I should have seen a decrease in the ad requests, it didn't happened, of course I'll wait more since only 400 active devices were updated with this new version(although I think it should have been reflected in the statistics already).

It is really frustrating, feels like I have no control over this, is there other reasons for admob to have low match rate? can someone help me here? Thanks all in advance.

Comment: It's hard to fix a problem if you don't know where the problem is & to me, it seems like some of the assumptions made above could be checked by making an experimental build that logs requests, side loading it on a test device & testing. I would include an equal amount of play time & not play time. After a day, pull the logs & check to see if the number of requests matches the play test experience.

Comment: Hmm it may be the only option now, to keep digging it.